# How can I write data into text file at fastest speed?

Tags: php

It takes quite long if I random generate 4 billion IP address, and write them into a text file. Do you guys have better idea to finish this action faster?

this is my code

```
$ip_long = array(

            array('607649792', '608174079'), //36.56.0.0-36.63.255.255

            array('1038614528', '1039007743'), //61.232.0.0-61.237.255.255

            array('1783627776', '1784676351'), //106.80.0.0-106.95.255.255

            array('2035023872', '2035154943'), //121.76.0.0-121.77.255.255

            array('2078801920', '2079064063'), //123.232.0.0-123.235.255.255

            array('-1950089216', '-1948778497'), //139.196.0.0-139.215.255.255

            array('-1425539072', '-1425014785'), //171.8.0.0-171.15.255.255

            array('-1236271104', '-1235419137'), //182.80.0.0-182.92.255.255

            array('-770113536', '-768606209'), //210.25.0.0-210.47.255.255

            array('-569376768', '-564133889'), //222.16.0.0-222.95.255.255

        );

        $rand_key = mt_rand(0, 9);

        $handle = fopen('ip_data.dat', 'a+');
        for ($i=0; $i<4000000000; $i++) {
            $ip= long2ip(mt_rand($ip_long[$rand_key][0], $ip_long[$rand_key][1]));
            fwrite($handle, decbin( ip2long( $ip )) . "\r\n");

        }
```

Comment: Do you know what is taking the time - generating the random ip address, converting it, or writing it? Performance improvements are very specific - you need to benchmark your code then home in on the trouble spots.

Comment: 4 billion * ~12 bytes per IP = ~50GB of data to write. That will take some time no matter how you slice it. So find out what a practical sustainable sequential write speed for your storage system is and see if what you are getting is actually reasonable.

Comment: The fastest way is probably to create a string and write it every million or so...but you're writing 55 GB to a file if you do this.

Comment: You do a `long2ip` followed by a `ip2long`. Leaving both of those steps out, times 4 billion, should do something...

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but I can't believe generating 4 billion IP addresses is the way to do it.

Comment: Define "long".  You're probably going to be limited by the write speed of your hard disk.  Typical write speeds are around 100 MB/s, you have 4e9 * ~16 = 64e9 bytes to write, so it will take around 10 minutes to write this out.

Comment: What are you **REALLY** trying to do? What kind of problem did you have where the best course of action is to write **50GB** to a file?!?

Comment: `decbin` turns the IP address into a binary string (32 bytes) - so file size is far worse than you think...

Comment: why not write a binary file? It would be 4 bytes per IP.

Comment: I think this is a good question to be asked because regardless of what they are trying to do it raises a common issue.

Answer (score 5):

Because of the restricted ranges that you identified, the total number of distinct values that you can generate is considerably smaller than 4 billion (depending on the value of `$rand_key`, which is only evaluated once, it's never more than about 79*256*256 ~ 5M ) - so you are going to gets lots of duplicates. That being the case, you will be much faster if you generate an array of strings - one for each valid IP address in the range. Then pick a random string from that list and append it to a string. Write the string when it gets to a typical block size, set it back to `""` and repeat.

More importantly, I question how sensible it is to use `decbin` - it turns your IP string into lots of ones and zeros, so a simple IP address will take 32 bytes (plus `\r\n`, that's 34). Multiply by 4G, and you have 120G+. That's actually a lot more data than the 50 GB that @Jon was computing above...

If you store the IP address as a binary number instead there will be just four bytes per number - and you might as well leave the CRLF off at that point.  It will be faster to write, faster to read.  So the suggestion becomes:

1. Create an array with the range of valid values (this is a range of integers; would like to think of them as unsigned but that is not a type that php knows about)
2. Pick a random value from the array (random index)
3. Put the value pointed to by the random index into another array (of predefined size - 2048 elements is good)
4. Do a binary write of this array when you filled it
5. Repeat

What you end up with is a file full of random binary numbers each of which represents an ip address. It's very fast (although it still involves writing a 16G file - but that's as small as it can get).

Comment: you're right..the total amount of all IPv4 addresses is 4,294,967,296. (2^32) And not to mention all the reserved addresses..

Comment: @redreggae - if you look at the logic, the code is generating random addresses for a very small subset of addresses... never more than 5M distinct ones.

Comment: yes I saw it..he only uses small IP ranges. So I totally agree with you that he gets lots of duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're writing 50GB of data, your disk is most likely your bottleneck. A few suggestions

1. Stop calling fwrite so often - build up roughly 1000 values, then fwrite them all at once, try the same with 10000 values, measure the performance
2. Use C... or better yet assembly
3. Buy a hard drive with higher RPM or solid state memory

Comment: I wouldn't go quite as far as assembly, although maybe I'm just too young to understand why anyone would want to go through that pain

Comment: @Bojangles - usually a good C compiler with `-O3` can optimize in ways that most folks who "roll their own assembler" wouldn't even dream of. One can do a lot of other optimization before resorting to assembler. Unlike you, I am old enough - there was a time (mid '80s) I wrote assembler for a 6502 processor where the alternative was BASIC but I had to access memory (the other 32k) that was unavailable to the interpreter...

Answer (score 0):

Don't run heavy functions in loops. Incrementing a variable and then writing *once* is much better. Note that the amount of data you write in the example still is extremely heavy, so I chose to guess that it was just an "immense" number in order to really get time differences to show while trying to tweak you functions.

```
$ip_long = array(

        array('607649792', '608174079'), //36.56.0.0-36.63.255.255

        array('1038614528', '1039007743'), //61.232.0.0-61.237.255.255

        array('1783627776', '1784676351'), //106.80.0.0-106.95.255.255

        array('2035023872', '2035154943'), //121.76.0.0-121.77.255.255

        array('2078801920', '2079064063'), //123.232.0.0-123.235.255.255

        array('-1950089216', '-1948778497'), //139.196.0.0-139.215.255.255

        array('-1425539072', '-1425014785'), //171.8.0.0-171.15.255.255

        array('-1236271104', '-1235419137'), //182.80.0.0-182.92.255.255

        array('-770113536', '-768606209'), //210.25.0.0-210.47.255.255

        array('-569376768', '-564133889'), //222.16.0.0-222.95.255.255

    );

    $rand_key = mt_rand(0, 9);

    $ip = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<40000; $i++) {
        $ip .= decbin( ip2long( long2ip(mt_rand($ip_long[$rand_key][0], $ip_long[$rand_key][1])))) . "\r\n";
    }
    $handle = fopen('ip_data.dat', 'a+');
    fwrite($handle, $ip);
```

Comment: Were we're going, we don't _need_ memory limits

Comment: if in doubt, add another petabyte of memory :D